# How to filter or obtain by "group by" the ODD string characters of a List[String] in scala?

Tags: scala

```
/*>(IMPARES (A B C))
(A C)
>(IMPARES (A B C D E F))
(A C E)
>(IMPARES ()) 
NIL*/
```

I've tried to obtain the odd positions of the characters and then `println()` the odd characters.

```
  def IMPARES (L: List[String]): List[String]={
    if (L.isEmpty) List("it is empty")
    else (IMPARES(List{L.indexOf(`enter code here`)}))
  }
```

I expect the odd characters of a `List[String]`.

Comment: You could at least make sure the code is formatted correctly. Also, it is unclear what the question is? What problem do you have? - I understand that you want to filter only odd positions of a **List**, since this is more than obvious that it is homework, I guess you have some restrictions that you must made clear, like can you use any function available in the standard library? Or some subset of that? Maybe just a few helpers that are already defined? Or probably you should solve this with just recursion and basic operations? - Finally, you should show any attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another simple way you can achieve this:

```
 val l = List("AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF")

 l.grouped(2)   // group your list in List of 2 > List(List(AB, BC), List(CD, DE), List(EF))
   .map(_.head) // take only the 1. element
   .toList      // change iterator to List again > List(AB, CD, EF)
```

Comment: Thanks.
That was very helpful !!